# Can I get information from Excel without Microsoft Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel

So, I'm very limited with what I can do with vb at work.  The edition of vb.net they set me up with doesn't have the files to use the microsoft.office things, and they won't give me permissions to download them.  Is there any other way to pull all the information in column E of a spreadsheet?

Thank you for any insight you might be able to give me.

Comment: If they wont give their programmers the tools they need they don't deserve to have programmers.

Comment: [You can](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6108145/11683). Just switch `Option Strict` off

Comment: Are you targeting .Net client framework by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`late binding`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304661/en-us). From the linked page:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objApp As Object
    Dim objBook As Object
    Dim objBooks As Object
    Dim objSheets As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Dim range As Object

    ' Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
   objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks
    objBook = objBooks.Add
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets
    objSheet = objSheets.Item(1)

    range = objSheet.Range("A1")

    'Set the range value.
    range.Value = "Hello, World!"

    'Return control of Excel to the user.
    objApp.Visible = True
    objApp.UserControl = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @jkeefe - Note that you should consider late binding evil in general (since it hamstrings the compiler's ability to catch typos, among other things). Since it's necessary in this case to get your job done, try to isolate the code completely that deals with Excel, and keep `Option Strict` on everywhere else.

Comment: I wouldn't call it *evil*. It's not the *preferred* or *easiest* way, and you do have to make sure you test your code thoroughly and to only use features that are available in commonly used versions of Office instead of the latest and greatest, though. :-) Many times late binding is necessary, when there's not information available for early binding or when you're not sure something is installed on a user's system.

Comment: I had no idea that's possible, very cool, is it exclusive to VB.Net?

Comment: @JMK: No. :-) It's available in any language that can use COM and the `IDispatch` interface. Go to the page I linked, copy and paste the page title into the Search box, and change `Visual Basic` to `C#`, and you'll find the same article there. You can do the same thing (more code, of course) in C++. It's also available for much more than working with MS Office (like the Windows Shell, for instance).

Comment: Well I learned something new today, thanks! Just to add, if the OP actually has Excel installed on their machine, and they aren't seeing the Interop library in the references dialogue box, it's probably just because they are targeting client framework as opposed to full framework though.

Comment: How would I change that?  To target full framework...because I do have excel installed.

Comment: How would you change *what*? My comment about limitations had nothing to do with the "framework". It had to do with using late binding when you distribute your application to end users (other than you) who might not have the most recent version of Office installed, because using features that weren't there would cause problems. If you only want to use it on your machine, you can use any features of Excel you want - if it works, you're fine.

Comment: I was referring to JMK's comment that if the "OP has excel installed on their machine and they aren't seeing the interop library in the references dialogue box, it's probably just because they are targeting the client framework..." but I think I found it.

Comment: @jkeefe56: Ah, got it. I read the comment, but before it was edited to include that info. (It read "Well I learned something new today, thanks!". :-)  When you're addressing a comment to a specific person, you should use `@` before their name (as I did with this to you) so the right person gets notified - I got it instead of JMK, because you posted it to my answer. Also, your question here was about Excel without interop, which was answered. If the answer to that question was satisfactory, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) .

Answer (score 2):

@KenWhite gave the right answer in regards to Excel without Interop, but all you really needed to do was to change the target framework to access the libraries.

You can do this like so. First of all, right click on your project in Solution Explorer and go down to **Properties**. At this point, you should see a Project properties page, with a **Target framework** dropdown box, change this from **.NET Framework x.x (Client Profile**) to **.NET Framework x.x**.

Now, you can simply select the **References** tab in the Properties window, click on **Add** and add **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**.